# PHP: function with unknown type of parameter

Tags: php, oop

I have a function as

```
public function calculateAge()
{
 // do calcualtions here
}
```

and this function should accept one object as argument but different type. For example,

```
$dog = new Dog();
calculateAge($dog);

$cat = new Cat();
calculateAge($cat);
```

As you can see, I am trying to pass dog object and cat object to the function. How can define the calculateAge function so that it will take different type object as argument. How can I write a funtion that takes unknown type of parameter.

Comment: Why not have the function in the class?

Comment: Make your Dog and Cat classes extend a common interface (e.g. `Animal`), and typehint to that interface

Comment: You really should do your own homework

Comment: @Mark, could you please show in code. I need the solution your way. Thanks

Comment: [example code](https://3v4l.org/OIj8b)

Comment: @MarkBaker Y U NO use interface, instead of abstract class? Also why not move the `+hello` method in said interface

Comment: @DaGhostmanDimitrov - because I was trying to keep it simple, as an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in your case you need at to make sure your function `calculateAge` is able to calcualte the age of the passed object. For instance, to calculate the age of the object (it seems that it's an animal :) ), your function `calculateAge` knows that whatever the type of the object, it has a method called `getAge` that does the job.
So all what you need to do in `calculateAge` is to call `getAge` of the passed object.

You can do this for instance:

```
interface Animal
{
    public function getAge();
}

// The same thing for the class Dog
class Cat implements Animal
{
     public function getAge()
     {
           // code to calculate age
     }
     ...
}

public function calculateAge(Animal $animal)
{
    echo $animal->getAge();
}

$dog = new Dog();
calculateAge($dog);

$cat = new Cat();
calculateAge($cat);
```